# étagère à livres vs bibliothèque

Tags: sens

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9tag%C3%A8re/31251) gives 2 definitions of "étagère":

> Tablette fixée horizontalement à un support vertical. ex : Les étagères d'une bibliothèque.
>
> Meuble formé d'un ensemble de tablettes superposées.

It seems to me that the first meaning translates to English as "shelf" and the second meaning translates to English as "rack" or "shelving unit". [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A9tag%C3%A8re) agrees with that. I guess that an "étagère à livres" is a synonym of "bibliothèque" (bookcase). Is that right? Is there any difference in meaning between both?

Comment: Une étagère à livres ne désigne pas une bibliothèque, mais une partie d’une bibliothèque. De plus, sur une étagère à livres — au format adapté pour des livres —, on peut déposer n’importe quel objet. D’autre part, une bibliothèque d’une seule étagère ne correspond pas au grec ancien  «  βιβλιοθήκη, bibliothếkê (« lieu de dépôt de livres »). Les deux mots ne sont pas interchangeables. Pour les autres définitions : https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/biblioth%C3%A8que

Comment: @Personne Qu'en est-il de la deuxième signification du terme "étagère" donnée dans les dictionnaires Larousse et Word Reference ? Si étagère peut être un "meuble formé d'un ensemble de tablettes superposées", il serait logique que "étagère à livres" soit une bibliothèque. Ce n'est peut-être pas un terme habituel pour une bibliothèque, mais il me semble qu'il peut signifier cela.

Comment: Une étagère qui désigne par glissement sémantique un meuble composé d’étagères sera appelé bibliothèque s’il comporte des livres, rayons dans un super-marché etc. L’étiquette qui défini un meuble s’efface devant son utilisation : si un gamin dit « Oh la grande étagère à livres » on lui répondra, « cela s’appelle une bibliothèque »

Comment: @Personne J'ai déjà entendu (par des adultes) des *étagères à livres*, on en vend (voir sites de e-commerce). Beaucoup d'adultes n'emploieraient pas le mot bibliothèque à la place parce que c'est un mot qui ne fait pas partie de leur vocabulaire (même si je pense qu'ils le comprennent). Question de langue qui reflète une différence sociale. Celui qui a beaucoup de livres chez lui  et pour qui les livres ont de l'importance dira « bibliothèque », celui qui n'a que quelques livres parlera d'« étagère à livres » par opposition aux étagères occupées par les assiettes, bibelots et autres...

Comment: @None — Bien que je ne me souvienne pas avoir entendu *étagère à livres*, il est vrai que pour désigner une étagère qui accueille les livres parmi d’autres qui n’ont pas la même destination, *étagère à livres* convient parfaitement, la destination de cette étagère particulière est bien *des livres*, bibliothèque ne convient pas ici. Dans ma première réponse j’avais en tête "étagère = meuble". Les deux termes ne sont pas interchangeables à mes yeux, ils peuvent marquer dans un dialogue la position du locuteur par rapport aux livres.

Answer (score 1):

If you only say "étagère", this can be a **shelf** or a **shelving unit**, that's what WordReference tells you. If you say "étagère à livres", you're more precise, and it indeed has the same meaning as "bibliothèque", but "étagère à livres" is never used (at least, after 18 years, I've never heard it).

Be aware however of "étagère de livres" which means **shelf of book**. So, a "bibliothèque" is composed of "étagères de livres". I hope you will not be confused.

Comment: 1) *Étagère à livres*  is sometimes used, mostly in trade, to specify the use of the shelf, although the preferred (and to my mind better) term would me *étagère pour livres*. 2) *Étagères de livres* designates the content, not the piece of furniture, if the *bibliothèque* is empty you cannot say it is "compose of *étagères de livres". *Étagère de livres* would translate as  "shelf of book**s**" (i.e. "shelf filled with books").

Comment: So the short answer is that "étagère à livres" is a synonym of "bibliothèque" (when it means "bookcase"), but it is not usual.